# Interaction between cash register and card terminal

Tags: pci-dss, credit-card, identity

A store allows you to join their loyalty club by simply presenting an ID and a credit card. Your identity is somehow linked to your card and automatically registered the next time you pay, no extra actions required. This means the store is able to uniquely identify your credit card, but how? Directly using the card # is not secure, as it  could be stolen in case of an incorrectly/maliciously configured cash register. The card reader and cash register are two separate devices from different manufacturers, so an identifier must be sent by the reader to the cash register. How is this done without modifying the actual card and complying with data security standards?

Comment: (might no longer apply)...The card reader has to talk to the register anyways, which usually will include the card number, since the company will want, for their own records, to know what the card used was.  If a card won't read (stripe damaged), you usually type it in on the register, not the pad.  The big credit card breaches you hear about are (usually) against store servers, not the pin pads.  After that, it's a simple key lookup, although it wouldn't surprise me if somewhere on one of the tracks there was a "client" identifier (for when the card number changes)

Comment: I've never seen a loyalty club that identified you based on your credit card, unless they also were the company that issued you that card.  Where did you see this?

Comment: @Bobson Same, all the stores I have "loyalty program membership" status with seem to have my address on file, which was asked of me when I registered.

Answer (score 2):

> Your identity is somehow linked to your card and automatically
>   registered the next time you pay, no extra actions required.

Your name is on the card, electronically.  When they swipe your card the computer reads your name off the mag strip and they know that you're John Doe:

[image: Wikipedia ISO/IEC 7813 Track 1 examples]

Credit/Debit cards follow the [ISO/IEC 7813 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_7813) for the data on the mag stripe, and the NM field is 2-26 characters of Name.

You can see the same type of thing when you go to the airport.  The airline check-in kiosks ask for identification, and inserting a credit card is one method.  It does not have to be the card that you used to purchase the tickets; they're just grabbing your name off the card.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly how your name gets on receipts, but it doesn't really address the question of being linked to a loyalty program.  Of course, it's possible (even likely) that the OP is misinterpreting what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

An answer to your question will be difficult based on these conditions:

1. What if an already registered loyalty shopper replaces their credit card through its expiring system or a compromise? The system will not be able to identify them unless the operator painstakingly relink that new card to the same customer.
2. A simple cash register machine does not have a complex RDMS to handle and store data for a robust Loyalty program. You would need a structured network and a POS program tied with a Loyalty card system.
3. No programmer would ever use a field from credit cards to identify a customer. It's just not feasible. The need for a dedicated unchangeable primary key/identifier will be an issue plus other security concerns.

   I would suggest each customer gets a Loyalty card from the host system to uniquely and statically identify them in the sense where if that card is lost, a new replacement can be generated with the old loyalty ID/card number.